# VBA Open multiple files in selection to copy into mastersheet

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro in VBA (excel) to open a specific range of a daily file which all have a similar start of the name (9489) followed by a file specific date (DD-MM-YY). The selection is then copied into the masterfile (Masterfile.xlsm), this sub is run for all the files from the directory.

Since today however I keep getting an error named "Run-time error 1004: 9489 150116 Daily Dashboard.xlsx could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct."

Why do I get this error? Most importantly, can anybody help me solve this error? I did not change the spelling of the file or the files location!

**The code:**

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory() 
Dim Myfile As String 
Dim erow 
Myfile = Dir("F:\WGD\Dep 408101-Se-DCIFINK-009786\Consolidatie & Regulatory Reporting\Regulatory Reporting\Daily dashboard of Ratios\Test Daily Dashboard\")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Do While Len(Myfile) > 0 
If Myfile = "Masterfile.xlsm" Then

Exit Sub

End If

Workbooks.Open (Myfile) 
Worksheets("Liquidity Reporting").Range("A2:E19").Copy

Windows("Masterfile.xlsm").Activate 
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 5))

Workbooks(Myfile).Application.CutCopyMode = False 
Workbooks(Myfile).Close SaveChanges:=False

Myfile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: why would you go through the trouble of taking and posting a screenshot of the code instead of pasting it..?

Comment: new to stackoverflow! Thanks for the advice

Comment: why did you revert my edit and make your code unreadable again? Use four spaces to indent code so it gets formatted correctly. (e.g. by selecting it and clicking the {} button in the editor)

Comment: Didn't realize you could change it

Comment: indent the whole block, do not add `s around every line so you get syntax highlightning. I changed it now

Answer (score 2):

The reason that Excel cannot find the file is that MyFile is just the filename; you need to also include that file path.

This line: `ActiveSheet.Paste Destination...` will throw an error.

Try to avoid select and activate.

There is no need to size a range when using copy and paste.  You just need to target the top left cell of the destination range.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const FOLDERPATH = "F:\WGD\Dep 408101-Se-DCIFINK-009786\Consolidatie & Regulatory Reporting\Regulatory Reporting\Daily dashboard of Ratios\Test Daily Dashboard\"
    Dim Myfile As String
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range

    Myfile = Dir(FOLDERPATH)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While Len(Myfile) > 0
        If Myfile <> "Masterfile.xlsm" Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Set Target = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End With

            With Workbooks.Open(FOLDERPATH & Myfile)

                Set Source = .Worksheets("Liquidity Reporting").Range("A2:E19")
                Source.Copy Destination:=Target
                .Close SaveChanges:=False

            End With

        End If
        Myfile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx#Anchor_2) example I would have thought that it took some path as default. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you used `ChDir "F:\WGD\..."` Excel would be able to open the file just using it's name but you will still have to supply the path to the Dir function.  It is best just to use this pattern: [Dir Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Ahh changing the directory makes sense. (not that I want to use it that way, was just curious about the example)